# Why are my XPS JBL speakers crackling (static sound)?

Tags: speakers, dell-xps

I own a XPS L502X laptop which has inbuilt JBL 2.1 speakers.
I use Ubuntu 12.04.
I regularly use this ear training software called [GNU Solfege](http://solfege.org).
The issue is that my speakers make a static sound a lot when notes are played.
Not just that. It also shrieks sometimes when songs are played.

**About the sound**, it happens in particular parts of a song.
I mean, something like if it happens from 0:25 - 0:28 of a song and I rewind it back to 0:25 ,the sound still comes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Xavierjazz might be almost right. If the crackling sound occurs in the same place of the song every time it may mean that it has been recorded 'too loud' and something called [clipping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipping_%28audio%29) occurs. Try obtaining a different version of the same music file and check if this occurs. If it does and you are 100% sure that this is a different recording of the song then you may have other problems with your system. Try reinstalling drivers, chose a different version, maybe use one before the newest driver version.

Also, I'm using 702x, but the hardware might be comparable. Dell has messed up the system massively and random crackling occurs when listening to music while there is network traffic (not internet, but LAN).
Not an option for me, but maybe switching off wifi and connecting via ethernet cable may help alleviate the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that you have the volume set too loud and they are distorting. Try turning the volume down.

Answer (score 2):

Check if the same noises occur when you use Windows. If so, it must probably be some driver problem or a bug based on the OS.

Answer (score 0):

You can put some fabic or somthing under JBL box, you will have more vibrations but no static sound.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on my XPS L502X and it was a loose screw near the JBL box...

Answer (score 0):

Dell xps 15 L501x sub woofer giving crackling sound

Hi you can detached or disconnected the subwoofer cable, for temporary or permanent fix, as the speaker sound also produced good quality sound..

here how i disconected the subwoofer cable, it easy to find at the bootoom, see also utube video inside the link given below

http://atozcs.net/dell-xps-l501x-subwoofer-produce-distorted-crackle-sound/

Comment: Although this may answer the question, you should give a more detailed description of the linked content and explain how it relates to the question. This will help ensure that this answer remains useful in the event the linked page is removed or goes offline. For more information, see [this Meta Stack Exchange post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259).